# Objective-C NSMutableArray of sockets?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sockets, arraylist, nsmutablearray

I want to store a couple of sockets in an ArrayList/NSMutableArray, but the sockets are of type int and NSMutableArray only accepts objects (id). Is there another data type that I can use as a container for sockets? I am not sure how many entries I will have, so I would like the data container to be like an ArrayList.

Thanks!

EDIT: I've tried to send the socket as an NSNumber, but it did not work and caused XCode to crash when I tried to send a message using the socket.

Comment: Can you post the code you tried? Because usually, it works well. Maybe you didn't get the intValue out of the NSNumber

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should wrap up your file descriptors in [`NSFileHandle`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileHandle_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instances, these will play nice inside collection objects such as `NSArray` and are designed to wrap around file descriptors such as sockets. They also allow you to use standard Foundation types such as `NSData` in conjunction with your communication.

```
int s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

if (s != -1)
{
    // bind or connect to address

    NSFileHandle *mySock = [[NSFileHandle alloc] initWithFileDescriptor:s closeOnDealloc:YES];

    [myMutableArray addObject:mySock];
}
```

Note that `NSFileHandle` also provides convenience methods for accepting connections asynchronously, as well as asynchronous I/O. You can get the original file descriptor back by using the `fileDescriptor` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your int in an NSNumber like:

```
NSNumber *socket = [NSNumber numberWithInt:socketInt];
[myArray addObject:socket];
NSNumber *getSocket = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];
int getSocketInt = [getSocket intValue];
```

[More here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: So, you should post the code that you tried. Some memory management issue here for sure

Comment: Ah, actually you're right. Thanks! I was doing this: [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(sendMessage:) toTarget:self withObject:socket]; and socket was an int. I converted it to early.

Comment: yeah, just put NSNumber there and wrap out whenever you really need int:)